# android packages installation in windows

Tags: android

When I am trying to download and install Android packages I got this error

```
File not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-2.2_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
```

how to solve this???

Comment: actually it´s not a programming question...when does the error appear? What draws attention is that you want to install for windows but the filename says "..linux"

Comment: @dan Actually I believe that the samples for Windows also use the ...linux.zip file, as they won't be binaries

Answer (score 5):

You must run Android SDK as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

As @LeiNaD_87 mentioned you probably will need admin access to drive. I recommend installing Android SDK in another a drive different from OS drive so that there is no issue of access. Also if still issue persists you can take a look at some sites which offer offline setups for Android SDK.